# Link changes in the browser but the component doesn't render Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

The following code does change the link in the browser but the component doesn't render that should at the link. It used to work earlier when I didnt have the timer but despite doing clearTimeout() it still does the same.

```
constructor(private QuizService: QuizService, private route: 
ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private http: Http ) {
    this.score = 0;

  }

nextQuestion()
  {
    if(this.id==1)
    {
      this.questionTime=performance.now();
      setTimeout(() => 
      {
        CountdownTimerComponent.prototype.update();                    
        this.router.navigate(['/' + (this.id + 1)]);
        this.nextQuestion();
      },
      11000);
    }
    else
    var foo=setTimeout(() => 
    {
      this.questionTime=performance.now();
      CountdownTimerComponent.prototype.update();
      if(this.id<this.qNumber){
      this.router.navigate(['/' + (this.id + 1)]);
      this.nextQuestion();
    }          
    else{
     clearTimeout(foo);
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/score');
     //even the following doesnt work
     //this.router.navigate(['score']);

    }
    },
    11000);
  }
```

Here's my Router:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: ':id', component: QuizComponent },
  { path: 'score', component: ScoreComponent },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, 
{ useHash: true });
```

Comment: there are a problem using children in your routes

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: put your appRoutes: Routes. be careful, the first match is the component rendered

Comment: list your router configuration to help us see what might be wrong.

Comment: Reorder the appRoutes (put path'score' before path':id'. And you must observable router changes like show https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse

Comment: Eliseo Thanks. That worked. Post it as an answer so I can mark it correct. :)